# Rails assign session variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm hacking around Rails the last 8 months so don't truly understand a number of things. I've seen and used helper methods that set the current_user etc. and am now trying to replicate something similar.

I'm trying to set a global value in the application controller for the current company the user is in. I know I'm doing it wrong but I can't quite figure out how to solve it or even if I'm approaching it correctly. I want it so that when the user clicks on a company, the global variable is set to the id of the company they are in. Then in any other sub-model, if I want info on the company, I use the global variable to retrieve the company object with that id.

The code that's causing the problem is in my navbar in **application.html.erb**

```
<li><%= link_to "Company", company_path, :method => :get %></li>
```

This works when I'm using the companies controller etc. But when I try use any other controller I'm getting the error

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Employees#index

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"companies"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

which as I understand it means it can't render the url because no company id parameter is being passed?

I was trying to hack a helper method I used in another project (for getting the current_user) but have realised that it uses the session to extract the user.id to return a user object. Here's my attempt at the helper method in **application_controller.rb**

```
def current_company
  @company = Company.find_by_id(params[:id])
end
```

I'm not able to get the current company from the session so my method above is useless unless the company id is being passed as a parameter.

I've thought about passing the company id on every sub-model method but

1. I'm not 100% sure how to do this
2. It doesn't sound very efficient

So my question is am I approaching this correctly? What's the optimal way to do it? Can I create a helper method that stores a global company id variable that gets set once a user accesses a company and can then be retrieved by other models?

I probably haven't explained it too well so let me know if you need clarification or more info. Thanks for looking.

> ***Edit 1***

Made the changes suggested by Ruby Racer and now I have:

> **application.html.erb**

```
 <%unless current_page?(root_path)||current_page?(companies_path)||current_company.nil? %>

   <li><%= link_to "Company", company_path, :method => :get %></li>
```

This is not displaying the link in the navbar, I presume because current_company is nil (the other two unless statements were fine before I added current_company.nil?

I'm setting the current_company in

> **companies_controller.rb**

```
before_action :set_company, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :company_home]

def company_home
  current_company = @company
  respond_with(@company)
end
```

> **application_controller.rb**

```
def current_company=(company)
  session[:current_company] = company.id
  puts "The current_company has been assigned"
  puts params.inspect
end

def current_company
  @company = Company.find_by_id(session[:current_company])
  puts "The current_company helper has been called"
  puts @company
  puts params.inspect
end
```

Am I doing something wrong?

> ***Edit 2***

I have no idea why this isn't working. After the above edits, it appears as though the `session[:company_id]` is not being assigned so the `current_company` helper method is returning nil. I've tried printing the session paramaters `puts session.inspect` and can't find any company_id information. Anyone any idea why it isn't assigning the value?

> **Edit 3**

Can't for the life of me figure out what's going wrong. I've tried multiple things including moving the `current_company = @company` into the `set_company` method in **`companies_controller.rb`** which now looks like this:

```
def company_home
  puts "Test the current company"
  puts "#{@company.id} #{@company.name}"
  puts params.inspect
end

 private
  def set_company
    @company = Company.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if @company.nil?||current_user.organisation_id != @company.organisation.id
    flash[:alert] = "Stop poking around you nosey parker"
    redirect_to root_path
    else
    current_company = @company
    end      
  end
```

The `company_home` method is being given a company object (I can see this in the console output below) but the `current_company` assignment is just not happening. Here's the **console output** for reference

```
Started GET "/company_home/1" for 80.55.210.105 at 2014-12-19 10:26:49 +0000                                                                                                      
Processing by CompaniesController#company_home as HTML                                                                                                                            
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"gfdhjfgjhoFFHGHGFHJGhjkdgkhjgdjhHGLKJGJHpDQs6yNjONwSyTrdgjhgdjgjf=", "id"=>"1"}                                                                                   
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 6  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1                                                                    
  Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies"  WHERE "companies"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1                                                                                
  Organisation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "organisations".* FROM "organisations"  WHERE "organisations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]                                                 
Test the current company                                                                                                                                                          
1 Cine                                                                                                                                                                            
{"_method"=>"get", "authenticity_token"=>"gfdhjfgjhoFFHGHGFHJGhjkdgkhjgdjhHGLKJGJHpDQs6yNjONwSyTrdgjhgdjgjf=", "controller"=>"companies", "action"=>"company_home", "id"=>"1"}                          
  Rendered companies/company_home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)                                                                                                     
  Company Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies"  WHERE "companies"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1                                                                            
The current_company helper has been called                                                                                                                                        

{"_method"=>"get", "authenticity_token"=>"gfdhjfgjhoFFHGHGFHJGhjkdgkhjgdjhHGLKJGJHpDQs6yNjONwSyTrdgjhgdjgjf=", "controller"=>"companies", "action"=>"company_home", "id"=>"1"}                          
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "organisations".* FROM "organisations"  WHERE "organisations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]                                                             
Completed 200 OK in 280ms (Views: 274.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

As per above, under the line `The current_company helper has been called`, there's a blank line where `puts @company` should be outputting something. This means the current_company method is returning nothing.

Also, in the `company_home` method in the companies_controller, if I change `puts "#{@company.id} #{@company.name}"` to `puts "#{current_company.id} #{current_company.name}"` an error gets thrown.

Has anyone any idea why the `def current_company=(company)` isn't assigning a session parameter? Thanks

> **Final Edit**

I've no idea why, but it appears the problem related to this:

```
def current_company=(company)
  session[:current_company] = company.id
  puts "The current_company has been assigned"
  puts params.inspect
end
```

It looks as though this never gets called. I don't understand why as I've never used something like this before.

I'll put my fix in an answer.

Comment: Yes, you are summoning `session[:id]` when you really need to access `session[:company_id]`

Comment: Changed it to 'session[:company_id]' but still not working

Comment: Is there a `rails_root/config/initializers/session_store.rb`? If so, is there any line uncommented?

Comment: Yes the commented line is '# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.'. Am using Devise. Would that make any difference?

Comment: Ok, I've got it... If it is as you have it here, remove spaces around `=` in this line: `current_company = @company` and make it `current_company=@company` and see if it works

Comment: I presume you mean in the `companies_controller` `company_home` method. Done that and not working

Comment: Ok, debugging comes next. It should be working, so there is something different going on that I cannot figure. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. Can I ask you about the `current_company=(company)` and `current_company` methods in `application_controller`. Is the first just a setter? Is it only called when an object is passed to it?

Comment: Yes,it's for assignment only.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, you need to do two things.

First thing, you need to assign your `company.id` to a session variable

```
def current_company=(company)
    session[:company_id]=company.id
end
```

Second, your helper method for current_company will be as follows:

```
def current_company
    Company.find_by_id(session[:company_id])
end
```

This can be nil if there is no `session[:company_id]` or if it corresponds to no company. That's ok...

Next, it is quite unlikely to get it working without an id, if you use `/companies` both for your index and your show actions.

Now, for your first task. Setting the variable:

controller:companies_controller.rb

```
def show
    # assuming you have a before_action, something like set_company, no need to redo it
    current_company=@company # this will set the session variable
end
```

If you want your navbar to lead to your `current_company`, you will need to write:

```
<% unless current_company.nil? %>
    <li><%= link_to "Company", current_company, :method => :get %></li>
<% end %>
```

I don't know what you want to do if there is no current company, so I just leave it out.

Comment: Thanks but I still can't get working. I'll edit my original post

Comment: @AlD In Rails Tutorial Michael Hartl used a similar technique to define `current_user`, check this out: https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_4_0_upgrade/blob/master/app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb

Comment: Just noticed your post D-side. I'll have a look at this thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a helper method to assign a value or search for a company, I've assigned a session variable in the `set_company` method in `companies_controller.rb`. This can then be accessed around the application

> **companies_controller.rb**

```
 private
    def set_company
       @company = Company.find_by_id(params[:id])

       if @company.nil?||current_user.organisation_id != @company.organisation.id
          redirect_to root_path
       else
          session[:current_company] = @company
          current_company = @company
       end      
    end
```